# Textbox not rendering entity reference in a correct format

Tags: html, xml, xslt, textbox, entityreference

In my web application, i have textbox whose value are got from Database. In DB the value of the textbox contains entity references such as &< etc but while rendering it on screen its not getting fetched correctly.

Example
Value in DB : `Hi &amp; How are you`

Output Coming : `Hi &amp; How are you`

Required output : `Hi & How are you`

```
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="@db-value ='' ">
                            <INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="db-value" VALUE="{para-description}" />
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                            <INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="db-value" VALUE="{@db-value}" />
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
```

I want the {@db-value} to appear correctly as mentioned in the example.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What does it show as in the source of the XML you're passing from the db to your XSLT?

Comment: its showing with the &amp; only not getting parsed.

Comment: its taking the value from DB and diplaying as it is .. i want that to parse and display as a special character not with &amp;

Comment: Sounds like your error is your code reading from DB and generating the source XML, as the string literal `&amp;` would need to be encoded as `&amp;amp;` if part of an XML file.

Comment: &amp; -> &
this is what i want.so there is no way of changing it from xml or html files itself ?

Comment: Within the HTML file, the `&` should always be encoded as `&amp;`, so it's unclear what the problem is?

Comment: Try using `<xsl:value-of select="@db-value" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>`.